# Angular main module depends on $templateCache.run() (submodule)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-templatecache

I'm trying to use `$templateCache` and have the following code:

All my templates are compiled in a `templates.js`:

```
angular.module("gm.templates", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {$templateCache.put("/app/app-mc3.html","<div class=.......
```

My main `app.js` loads it like this

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ct.ui.router.extras', 'gm.templates',.....
```

I'm loading the `templates.js` file before to load the `app.js`, but when I try to use the `$templateCache` in one of my services, it's defined but empty, meaning no template have been loaded yet.

Here are some logs of `$templateCache.info()` in my app.

```
ClientService-0.1.5.js:2 Object {id: "templates", size: 0}
ClientService-0.1.5.js:27 /app/app-mc3.html
ClientService-0.1.5.js:28 Object {} // console.log($templateCache)
ClientService-0.1.5.js:29 undefined // Trying to find a specific template in the $templateCache
ClientService-0.1.5.js:2 Object {id: "templates", size: 72}
app-0.1.5.js:3 Object {id: "templates", size: 72}
```

So, what I understand is that the templates are available but not at the beginning. It looks like it's a dependency order issue.

Does the `module.run()` of angular submodules is executed before the main entry point of my app? I have the feeling the injection is done correctly, but the `gm.templates` *run()* method is done asynchronously somehow to my services. How can I force the *submodule*.run() to be executed before I need it?

Comment: Please, post the code where "/app/app-mc3.html" is being used. $templateCache is synchronous, and `submodule.run` is executed before `module.run`.

Comment: @estus I use it in a service. here is the gist https://gist.github.com/Vadorequest/39b66554769d34a68b50

Comment: @estus indeed, `submodule.run` is executed before `module.run` but `submodule.run` isn't executed before `module.config`, so all the **gm.templates** are populated after my app as started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the list of your templates before your app is running, you can attach them to a window object.

You can do so by configuring the grunt/gulp task. (gulp coffee here)

Then you'll have all your templates in the `window.gtTemplates` object and can use them in your service. Note that `$templateCache` will also be populated as before.

```
TEMPLATE_HEADER = 'window.gmTemplates = {};'
TEMPLATE_BODY = 'window.gmTemplates["<%= url %>"] = "<%= contents %>";'
TEMPLATE_FOOTER = 'angular.module("<%= module %>").run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
    Object.keys(window.gmTemplates).forEach(function(url) {
        $templateCache.put(url, window.gmTemplates[url])
    })
}]);'

gulp.task 'template', ->
    gulp.src([
        'src/**/*.html'
        '!src/index.html'
    ])
    .pipe(templateCache(
        root: '/'
        module: 'app'
        templateHeader: TEMPLATE_HEADER
        templateBody: TEMPLATE_BODY
        templateFooter: TEMPLATE_FOOTER
    ))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/src/'))
```